# Explain the extra padding in struct.pack with native byte order

Tags: python

Can someone explain why I get extra bytes when I use native Byte order with struct.pack?

```
>>> import struct
>>> struct.pack('cI', 'a', 1)
'a\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'

>>> struct.pack('<cI', 'a', 1)
'a\x01\x00\x00\x00'
```

so the native Byte order has 'a' and then 3-(00 bytes) before it. Why does the native Byte order have these bytes while little endian or big endian byte order do not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is explain in the [`struct` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html):

> Note: **By default, the result of packing a given C struct includes pad bytes in order to maintain proper alignment for the C types involved;** similarly, alignment is taken into account when unpacking. This behavior is chosen so that the bytes of a packed struct correspond exactly to the layout in memory of the corresponding C struct. To handle platform-independent data formats or omit implicit pad bytes, use standard size and alignment instead of native size and alignment: see Byte Order, Size, and Alignment for details.

In the [Byte Order, Size, Alignment](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment):

> ....
>
> **Native size and alignment are determined using the C compiler's sizeof expression**. This is always combined with native byte order.
>
> ...
>
> Notes:
>
> 1. **Padding is only automatically added between successive structure
>      members.**
> 2. **No padding is added at the beginning or the end of the
>      encoded struct. No padding is added when using non-native size and
>      alignment, e.g. with ‘<’, ‘>’, ‘=’, and ‘!’.**
> 3. To align the end of a
>      structure to the alignment requirement of a particular type, end the
>      format with the code for that type with a repeat count of zero. See
>      Examples.

Comment: That definitely clears things up. I have more reading to do with how the C sizeof works with python types. But thank you, this gets me on the right track.